# Rake task is failing in cron job in Rails production app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I'm using the whenever gem to setup a cron job that backs up a Rails app's database once per week. It works fine in development, but in production it fails:

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit`
```

The error is saying "Missing secret_key_base", but I already have the production environment variables set in a .rbenv-vars file, and the app is running fine otherwise.

This is the generated cron job from whenever which causes the above error (it's set to every minute for testing purposes)

```
PATH=/home/deploy/wiki/doc_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin:/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin:/home/deploy/.rbenv/libexec:/home/deploy/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/deploy/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-vars/bin:/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/wiki/doc_app/releases/20210209173234 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake backup:db --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/deploy/wiki/doc_app/releases/20210209173234/config/schedule.rb at: 2021-02-09 11:41:37 -0600
```

When I run the generated command in the shell, it works fine, and runs the rake task no problem. What am I missing here?

schedule.rb

```
set :output, "log/cron_log.log"
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']

every 1.minute do
  rake "backup:db"
end
```

backup.rake

```
namespace :backup do
  desc "backup database"
  task db: :environment do
    settings = Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    file_name = "dump-#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}.sql"
    path = "#{ENV['HOME']}/backups/"
    full_path = path + file_name
    Backup.create!(path: full_path, name: file_name)
    system "if [ ! -d #{path} ]; then mkdir #{path}; fi; mysqldump -u #{settings['username']} -p#{settings['password']} --databases #{settings['database']} --ignore-table=#{settings['database']}.backups > #{full_path}"
  end
end
```

Comment: did you try to run rails credentials:edit? then adding the key under environment like 
production: secret_key_base

Comment: @AhmedAli It looks like this was an issue with rbenv-vars. My rake task was not picking up the environment properly, so I used figaro for environment variables instead and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by switching from rbenv-vars to the Figaro gem for environment variables. Everything is working now.